# `Background size: cover` fill up border

Tags: javascript, css

Is there any way to achieve the effect of `background-size:cover` whilst filling up the area behind the border as well. To illustrate this better take a look at the image below: the left image is using `background-size:cover` and neatly fills up the entire box itself **regardless** of whether the image is portrait or landscape, but is hidden behind the semi transparent top and bottom borders. The second image is created using a `background-size: auto 260px` rule which gives exactly the effect I want, however only works because I know that the background in this case is landscape (and that the box itself is `200px` and the border `30px`).

[image]

A JSFiddle which is used to render the above two boxes can be [found](http://jsfiddle.net/CMp8g/1/) here. I have a hard time believing this is not possible with pure css, but even open for javascript based solutions otherwise (although I could build a hackish Javascript solution I have no idea how to make on look relatively clean...). Still hoping there is a CSS way to do this though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This can be achieved by setting the [`background-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-origin) property to `border-box`:

```
#one{
    background-size:cover;
    background-origin: border-box;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CMp8g/2/)

There is also a `background-clip` property, which sounds like it should do that, but doesn't — since the background by default extends under the border, the question is rather why `background-size:cover/contain/%` don't take the border into account. Backwards compatability, I suppose.

Comment: could not believe that I missed out this property. However you should add detail on what value it should be set to (the `border-box` value).

Comment: Amazing, I knew about the `background-clip` property, but never realized what the `background-origin` was far. What a terribly unintuitive name if you ask me.

Comment: never in a million years would i have guessed. thank you!